# I/O past end of record on unformatted file when reading a binary file in fortran with form='unformatted'

Tags: c++, fortran

I try to read a binary file using `form='unformatted'` in Fortran-90 created by this C++ program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<assert.h>
#include<cmath>

template<typename T>
void write_binary_f_all(T *__restrict__ a,int size_a,const std::string &filename)
{
    int dummy;
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(filename.data(),"wb")) == NULL){
        printf("cannot open %s\n",filename.data());
        exit(1);
    }
    dummy = size_a;
    assert(fwrite(&dummy,sizeof(int),1,fp) == 1); // header
    assert(fwrite(a,sizeof(T),size_a,fp) == size_a);
    assert(fwrite(&dummy,sizeof(int),1,fp) == 1); // tail
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(){
    float a[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        a[i] = exp(-i * 20. / 13.21);
        printf("%e ",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    write_binary_f_all(a,10,"out.bin");
}
```

Then in Fortran, I use this block to read this binary file:

```
program main 
implicit none

real a(10)
integer i
open(10,file='out.bin',status='old',form='unformatted')
read(10) a(:)
print*,a 
close(10)
```

But this error was raised `Fortran runtime error: I/O past end of record on unformatted file`. I use gcc-9.3 compiler on Ubuntu-20.04.  What is the problem?

Comment: Can you explain why you think the C++ program creates the file format that your Fortran compiler is expecting for its input?  Also, why are you trying to create a non-standard file format instead of using something like stream access or some other form of interchange format?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. The Fortran sequential unformatted file format is not standardized. Whet exact format are you trying to write in C++? What kimd of recorf markers? It is much better to use stream access for communication with other languages.

Comment: With gfortran, the header/tail should be the size of the data block in bytes. Here you are writing `size_a` elements of size `sizeof(T)`, which I suspect is not 1 but 4.

Comment: See this question / answer for why to use stream access: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594798/reading-unformatted-fortran-file-in-matlab-which-precision/13617201#13617201

Comment: @M.S.B. and others. While I generally agree that the stream access is better, this doesn't address the question. Notice that here the goal is to write a file in C++ for input to a Fortran program, and the implementation is specified in the question. It's not entirely clear the OP can change the Fortran code, and sometimes it's not possible.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, if the person asking the question can explain the logic of what is being implemented then a Fortran expert can answer whether the logic is correct and a C++ expert can answer whether the implementation of that logic is correct. Writing a general C++ program to mimic a particular Fortran compiler's unformatted IO covering all edge cases is far too broad to be answered here, so at some point "don't do this" really is the best advice.

Comment: In this particular case, you are writing in your header that the following record is of `size_a` which gfortran will interpret as a number of bytes. You'll want instead the header to say that the record is of size `size_a*sizeof(float)` or some such.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, good point, the question is unclear on whether the Fortran code can be modified or not.  My interpretation of the question is that the Fortran code can be modified.  If the Fortran can't be modified, then the C++ code should probably write the record length at the start and end of each Fortran record.  The answer that I linked to suggests this.  If this approach is needed, than the solution becomes compiler dependent.  Some compilers use four bytes for this information, some eight bytes.